# Choosing a value from an Array of Jobs using an Input Function

Tags: python, list, input

I'm trying to create this job program and do not know how can I choose a name from a list using an input function. Here is what I'm trying to do.

```py
business_list = ["HR Manager", "IT Engineer", "Technician", "Office Manager", "Director"]

for item in business_list:
 print(item)


def business_name():
 business_input = input("Please state your business: ")

 if business_input is "HR Manager":
  print("There are 8 available slots for HR Manager.")

business_name()
```

Comment: Which programming language are you writing in? Please make sure to add it as a tag, or include it in the post! :D

Comment: Done, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest changing your `business_list` list to a dictionary, with the titles as keys (all uppercase, to minimise entry errors) and the available slots as values. It could look like:
`business_list = {"HR MANAGER":8,"IT ENGINEER":2,...}`

Your `business_name` function could then be:

```py
def business_name():
 business_input = input("Please state your business: ")
 try:
  slots = business_list[business_input.upper().strip()]
  print(f"There are {slots} available slots for {business_input}.")
 except: 
  print("No name found for {business_input}. Please try again.")
  business_name()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't have that much knowledge for the ideas that I have so I decided to ask here, thank you so much!